Kya hame yellow colour ka chadar bisa kar Sona chaiye?
Jo yellow colour hi vo bhagwan vishu ka colour vastre hi to uske colour ka chadar pe nhi Sona chaiye kisi ke pass shastre praman h

Welcome. Kindly rewrite your question in English as per the forum rules.
